# alert before anything load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to check if browser support `pdf` viewer or not before anything loads on page and then if `pdf` viewer is not enable, I want to display alert `pdf` viewer is not enable and redirect to some other page.

I tried

```
window.onload = function () {}

$(document).ready(function () { });

$( window ).load(function() { });
```

but it still shows page in background. I do not want to display page until it is confirmed that `pdf` viewer is installed. Please help.

Comment: You can use javascript from the HEAD section. Now how do you check for pdf viewer support?

Comment: @A.Wolff, I' m done with pdf viewer support functionality just about varification on page preload is remain to do.

Comment: What is your research ? Use Google before Stackoverflow.

Comment: [holdReady()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.holdready/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is enough to just hide the page, the you can put `style="display: none"` on root element and then if PDF is enabled you just show it

HTML

```
<html><head></head><body>
     <span id="hideItAll" style="display: none">
         ... Your content goes here ...
     </span>
</body>
```

And in javascript you just show it up

```
if( pdf ) document.getElementById('hideItAll').style.display = ''; else alert( ... );
```

Other approach is to redirect user on page with content after PDF check is ok

Comment: I think last option will be more better.